# how to split a string array after a fixed length

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, split

I have listbox  `userOptions`  of object type giving me  a result as

```
{ Number = 1, FName = "ABC", LName = "D" }    
{ Number = 2, FName = "EFG", LName = "E" }    
{ Number = 3, FName = "HIJ", LName = "F" }    
{ Number = 4, FName = "ABC", LName = "G" }
```

and need to store in a string array just the `FName` information like

```
string[] data  = new string[3];
string data[0]=ABC
string data[1]=EFG
string data[2]=HIJ
```

Also  to remove the duplicate data from FName too;

I tried with the following code ,but it is time consuming as i cant split the string array data  from `FName = "ABC"` to just `'ABC'`

```
for (int i = 0; i < userOptions.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (object items in userOptions)
    {
        devicedata = userOptions[i].ToString();
        string[] Arr = devicedata .Split(',');
        devdata[i] = Arr[1];                            
    }
}
```

here `devicedata`  gives me  this information    `{ Number = 1, FName = "ABC", LName = "D" }`
`Arr` splits the data as `FName = "ABC"`   and stores in  `devdata[i]`
how can i merge my above two code so that i can directly get the distinct data like

```
string data[0]=  ABC
string data[1]= EFG
string data[2]= HIJ
```

Comment: All code consumes time and as long as the numbers are below 1000 it can't really be relevant.

Comment: It seems you need `var result = userOptions.Select(s => s.FName).Distinct().ToArray();`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: this should be given as an answer. It is probably the most succinct way to accomplish the problem

Comment: You have a ListBox that gives you JSon fragments? What is `devicetype` ? I'm voting to close this, create a [MCVE] if you want actual help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, RossPeter: the incomplete code suggests the OP is doing a bit of JSon deserialization. Or CSV parsing, or ...

Comment: I also voted to close as this question seems very unclear, especially looking at the code sample. You have a nested for loop that is pulling each `item` from `userOptions`, but inside that for loop you are not using the `item` at all. You are basically looping over the entire `userOptions` collection an extra N*(N-1) times for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really getting JSON (which is weird) you could also just use a regular expression for a fairly simple solution.

Ungreedy:

```
   FName = "(.*)"
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/pCwz3r/1